# Insert returning an array with 1 object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am making an insert with native mongodb for nodejs and in some cases, using insert returns me an array with the object I inserted, but sometimes it does not. I don't understand why it is inconsistent like this, I only want the object i inserted (which now includes _id) without the array wrapper, or, always return it WITH that wrapper.

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time the second parameter to your callback won't be an array of the inserted documents is when the first parameter is non-null to indicate an error occurred.  See [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html).

Comment: I can confirm I handled the error properly and it didn't pop. I wouldn't have gotten the value at all in my client :| I shall test out what happens to the error in those 2 cases. I will reply what happened.

Comment: turns out im a dumb little monkey. a findOne function was returning the non array :D very hilarious